# How can I update css position when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
        var elementMoveWithScroll = $('.thing_to_scroll');

        $('.container_overflow').scroll(function() {

            var scrollElementPosition = elementMoveWithScroll.position();
            console.log(scrollElementPosition);

            elementMoveWithScroll.css('margin-left', scrollElementPosition+'px');

        });
```

When a I use a hardcoded value in the place of `scrollElementPosition` for example 50 this seem add the `margin-left:50px` on scrolling the container.
I want to be able to update the value of the `elementMoveWithScroll` so that it moves with the horizontal scroll, how can I do this?

Comment: Will this pickup mousewheel?

Comment: Couldn't you use `position:fixed`?

Comment: `position:fixed` would fix it to the document not to its parent element

Answer (score 1):

Use scrollElementPosition.left for horizontal and scrollElementPosition.top for vertical corresponding values.